# Conditional Formatting Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am working on a google sheet,I want to highlight the price change between 2 sheets.Based upon SKU.Mean if there is difference in the price **(col B)** in **sheet1 and sheet2** then that item should be highlighted.

I have done this functionality using **Google Apps script** but it is taking time to process the data in bulk.

I am looking to complete this using **inbuilt google functions(Conditional formatting rule).**

Is there a way to achieve this using Google inbuilt function.

Here is the sheet url : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i2rpqFLh-E7A3F2eAXj16dHILRuvyv4iRapkf13TbBQ/edit?usp=sharing

Expected Output : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xmJt3qjQF2JQD2kXivTPPjdbqkJaG_NMuSXTUexm0UI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have a few questions: In the 3rd row, the SKUs are different for sheet1 and sheet2, is this intended? I assume the SKUs in both sheets can be different and in different order as well? Also, why is 5th row highlighted (the prices are equally the same in sheet1 and sheet2)?

Comment: @carlesgg97 Yes,There can be different SKU in both sheets and in different order.For 5th please check again both sheet,That was my mistake.

Comment: I think that using Google Apps Script should be a faster and cleaner solution than using inbuilt google functions. If the issue is performance, could you please provide the code so I may find ways to optimise it? Also, is it possible that an SKU appears more than once in a sheet? Cheers

Comment: Thank you,But I am in the need of solution using conditional formatting rule.No SKU will not appear more than one in a both sheet each.

Comment: I don't understand why the top line in the expected output is highlighted since the prices are the same in ColumnB for both sheets.